# Write to session on Cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to store $this->Request->Data on a session so I can use it again in a different controller but when I do that I'm getting an error message.

The code:

```
$x_hours = $this->request->data;
$this->Session->write('x_hours', $x_hours);
```

The error I get is:

Error: Call to a member function write() on boolean
File \src\Controller\HomeController.php
Line: 59

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `$this->request->session()` rather than `$this->Session` in CakePHP 3:-

```
$this->request->session()->write('x_hours', $x_hours);
```

Details can be found in the [official docs](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html#accessing-the-session-object).

Comment: Thanks, that did it.

Comment: 3.6+: `$this->getRequest()->getSession()`